# Create this procedural animation with a script?

Tags: animation, scripting, modifiers

Ok, Im making trees using the skin modifier, which has the option to automatically make armatures along the curve when done extruding.

(each of the lines turns into a bone)
[image]

I want to animate these trees growing, so each bone has to scale from 0 to 1 one after the other. This is tedious, and wondering if there's a way to make this animation via script?

Comment: Recommend breaking this down. Creating the armature using the skin modifier in edit mode and animating I would consider as two separate steps.  I imagine you model a fully grown tree and then grow it, as opposed to starting from a zero tree.  Please consider the answer-er here. ,, be far less tedious not having to create the model.  Post a sample file. Most of the time doing something in the UI can be done in a scrpt. Are the bone names in some order ... Are vertex groups assigned.  There is a chasm between the long answer and the short answer. The short: yes there is a way.

Comment: @batFINGER sorry. worded question poorly - 1. the bones are named sequentially and 2. I have already made the tree with armature attached to each segment. I am asking purely about scripting for the ANIMATION of these bones